# lodash - difference to keep into consideration quatity as well

Tags: arrays, lodash

I'm trying to get the different values form two array.
I used the `difference()` method from lodash, but this does not keep into account quantities.

For instance, i have these two array:

```
var arr1 = [10018, 12285, 12285, 2405, 2413];
var arr2 = [10018, 2405, 12285];
```

if I call `difference()`, the result I get is the following:

`var difference = _.difference(arr1, arr2) // Result -> [2413]`

This happens because 12285 is present twice on the first array and only once on the second. My desired result is to keep that into account, and so the difference array would be `[2413, 12285]`

I've checked the documentation but I don't see any method that could help me with that.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from `arr2`, and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `arr1` using the Set. Whenever an item exists in the Set, remove it from the Set and filter it out of `arr1:

```js
const arr1 = [10018, 12285, 12285, 2405, 2413];
const arr2 = [10018, 2405, 12285];

const result = arr1.filter(function(n) {
  // if an item is in the Set, remove it an return false, else return true
  return this.has(n) ? !this.delete(n) : true;
}, new Set(arr2));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In my particular case, this was the only one that actually returned what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = [10018,12285,12285,2405,2413];
let b = [10018,12285,2405];
b.filter((b) => {
 let i = a.indexOf(b);
   if(i != -1)
    a.splice(i,1);
})
console.log(a);
```

didn't use lodash,i am not sure whether it is a good approach to solve it by using filter, but it works.

Comment: let me know what you think about it .

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any function that can help you in Lodash either. However, you can achieve what you're looking for using other functions.

I think this solution provides what you're looking for though beware that it mutates `arr1`.

```js
var arr1 = [10018, 12285, 12285, 2405, 2413];
var arr2 = [10018, 2405, 12285];

_.forEach(arr2, val => {
  _.pullAt(arr1, _.findIndex(arr1, _.partial(_.isEqual, val)));
});

console.log(arr1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```